# Add new colums with regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to create a new column of specific words that are in a particular column using pandas.
In this example:
I have a certain text and a list of words
I would like to locate those specific words in a new column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTx7P.png)

```
import re

txt = df['text']
x = re.findall(("apple|banana|orange"), txt)
print(x)
```

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

It is important to note that there are empty cells in the text column

Comment: You need to iterate over txt variable. Note that txt variable is not a string it is pandas series

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas Series.str.contains to filter the df and pass the results to a new columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["a"], ["applea"], ["bana"], ["bananak"], ["banana"], ["orange"]],columns=["fruits"])
df["new"] = df[df["fruits"].str.contains(pat=r"banana|apple|orange", na=True)]
```

```
>>> df
    fruits      new
0        a      NaN
1   applea   applea
2     bana      NaN
3  bananak  bananak
4   banana   banana
5   orange   orange
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html The docs clearly show how to handle NA values. I have added the na=True argument above as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do

```
df['text'].str.findall("apple|banana|orange")
```

Comment: Thank you
It did help
But I get the values as an array, and I want to get it as a single value
[ Apple]
[Banana]
[Apple]
[Apple]
[Banana]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list:

`lst = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']`

I would do:

```py
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        for item in lst:
            if item in row['txt']:
                df.loc[i, 'newcol'] = item
```

Maybe a little convoluted, but that works!